# Django 3.2 Model not instantiating properly in the register function

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I apologize if my mistake is incredibly simple but I am completely new to Django. Currently, my `models.py` currently contains 2 types of profiles extending off of the default Django User model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username


class PCOProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)

    org_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    org_phone = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default = False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user.username} | {self.org_name}"
```

I have a `views.py` file which contains 2 functions, one called `register` and another `register-pco` that collects base user information, as well as information related to only one of of these models as a form on the same page which will be submitted at the same time as the base user information:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .forms import UserRegistrationForm, UserProfileForm, PCOProfileForm

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        profile_form = UserProfileForm(request.POST)

        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save()

            # Hooking up user_profile model to django default user model
            profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user
            profile.save()

            username = user_form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been created. You can now login as {username}!')
            return redirect('login')

    else:
        user_form = UserRegistrationForm()
        profile_form = UserProfileForm()

    context = {'user_form':user_form, 'profile_form':profile_form, 'title':'Register'}
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', context)

def register_pco(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        pco_profile_form = PCOProfileForm(request.POST)

        if user_form.is_valid() and pco_profile_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save()

            # Hooking up pco model to django default user model
            pco_profile = PCOProfileForm.save(commit=False)
            pco_profile.user = user
            pco_profile.save()

            username = user_form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been created. You can now login as {username}!')
            return redirect('login')

    else:
        user_form = UserRegistrationForm()
        pco_profile_form = PCOProfileForm()

    context = {'user_form':user_form, 'pco_profile_form':pco_profile_form, 'title':'Register'}
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', context)

@login_required
def profile(request):
    return render(request, 'users/profile.html')
```

The problem I am currently experiencing is that when I submit the registration form on the `register-pco` path, it fails to instantiate a `PCOprofile` object while the base user information gets saved in the database just fine. The end result is a `TypeError at /register-pco/ save() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`. Additionally, the regular `register` path works just as expected, adding a user in the database with a corresponding profile.

For reference, I was following [this](https://www.botreetechnologies.com/blog/supporting-multiple-roles-using-djangos-user-model/) guide to try and get user types setup in a simple manner (via 1-1 fields) but it seems as if there might be something wrong with the way I am making the forms since the models themselves work (I tested them in the django shell).

Here is the forms.py file without the imports:

```
class UserRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username','email','password1','password2']

class UserProfileForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ['first_name','last_name']

class PCOProfileForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = PCOProfile
        fields = ['org_name','org_phone']
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not calling `save()` on the instance of form you created, but on the form class. So instead of this:

```
# Hooking up pco model to django default user model
pco_profile = PCOProfileForm.save(commit=False)
```

you should call it with the form instance you assigned into variable `pco_profile_form` a few lines above:

```
# Hooking up pco model to django default user model
pco_profile = pco_profile_form.save(commit=False)
```